# How to retrieve all value of child from Firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this database in Firebase, this my database structure

[My Database.json](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwqXADHL46SWNjB0clREa1UzY0E)

[My firebase structure.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVioW.png)

How do I get all of that value index, this is my code :

```
ref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        Map<String, Object> td = (HashMap<String,Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();

        List<Object> values = new ArrayList<Object>(td.values());
        Log.d("values ", String.valueOf(values));
        Iterator<Object> iterator = values.iterator();
        int length = (int) dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
        String[] sampleString = new String[length];
        while(i < length) {
            sampleString[i] = iterator.next().toString();
            Log.d(Integer.toString(i), sampleString[i]);
            i++;
        }
    }
```

That code just return index from the first values :

```
11-17 10:31:07.516 9032-9032/com.arf.tanamanku D/values: [112.788683, -7.281677, 4.983527183532715, 32.00, 1008, 62]
11-17 10:31:07.516 9032-9032/com.arf.tanamanku D/0: 112.788683
11-17 10:31:07.516 9032-9032/com.arf.tanamanku D/1: -7.281677
11-17 10:31:07.516 9032-9032/com.arf.tanamanku D/2: 4.983527183532715
11-17 10:31:07.516 9032-9032/com.arf.tanamanku D/3: 32.00
11-17 10:31:07.516 9032-9032/com.arf.tanamanku D/4: 1008
11-17 10:31:07.516 9032-9032/com.arf.tanamanku D/5: 62  
11-17 10:31:07.516 9032-9032/com.arf.tanamanku D/values: [112.788683, -7.281677, 4.983527183532715, 28.00, 1010, 83]
```

How do I get all index from fist values and second values? Anyone could help me please?

Comment: You've included a link to a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export button in your Firebase Database console. Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: I have edited my statement and included the json file of my database, you can download it. I hope you could help me Frank, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Set the listener to the node one level above (that is to the node which is the root of all your nodes you want to retrieve the values from).
This will give you a HashMap with those nodes keys as the HashMap keys and the nodes values as the HashMap values.

Comment: I already set my listener on node /Data, you can see at my database picture, but still can't get nodes keys from /Data. I just got the first value?